# InputStream read doesnt return -1

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

Hey I'm trying to send a file with java sockets but I'm having problems with read function of InputStream class. I've got this code

```
 InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    byte [] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    int totalLength = 0;

    while(-1 != (bytesRead = is.read(buffer))) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        totalLength += bytesRead;
    }
    bos.close();
    fos.close();
    is.close();
```

But it stops at the very end. I've examined this with System.err.println and with debugging and it seems like is.read never gives -1 as it should when the buffer ends.
So for example I've got a file which has 5000 bytes, first read() returns 4096, then 4 (the rest of the file) and then nothing which causes endless loop. What might be the problem?

I really appreciate any help you can provide because I've been stuck there for like two hours now.

Comment: Are you closing the stream from the other end or you have no control over the other end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> read never gives -1 as it should when the buffer ends

That's not correct. It shouldn't return -1 'when the buffer ends'. It will only return -1 when the *stream* ends, which won't occur until the peer closes the connection.

Comment: I believe this should be a comment.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisSavard It is an answer. It completely explains the behaviour that the OP is asking about.

Comment: In the new edit, you address directly what the OP did not understand properly. In the first version, you only stated that -1 will be returned when the peer is closed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard You missed the word 'only'. Makes all the difference.

Comment: I don't see any *only* word in your first post.